# MATLAB: Not able to close a tag

Tags: xml, matlab

I am novice MATLAB user. I am trying to write a XML scheme using the values from the MATLAB. I am facing problem in closing the tag. The tag closes before the root but I want to close it at the required. Might be some syntax error- If anyone can correct it.

```
%Generate XML // 
docNode = com.mathworks.xml.XMLUtils.createDocument('ESM_SIMULATION_TEST');
docRootNode = docNode.getDocumentElement;

timestamp = docNode.createElement('TimeStamp');
timestamp.appendChild(docNode.createTextNode(time));
docRootNode.appendChild(timestamp);

esmDevices = docNode.createElement('ESM_DEVICES');
docRootNode = docRootNode.appendChild(esmDevices); 

for i=1:tmp
fileName = docNode.createElement(sprintf('ESM_ID_%d',i));
fileName.appendChild(docNode.createTextNode(files(i)));
docRootNode.appendChild(fileName);
end

thisElement1 = docNode.createElement('Total_Devices');
thisElement1.appendChild(docNode.createTextNode(sprintf('%d',y)));
esmDevices.appendChild(thisElement1);

thisElement1 = docNode.createElement('TOTAL_AMPERAGE');
thisElement1.appendChild(docNode.createTextNode(sprintf('%d',int16(amp))));
esmDevices.appendChild(thisElement1);

thisElement = docNode.createElement('RANDOM_ESM_DEVICES');
docRootNode = docRootNode.appendChild(thisElement); 

for i=1:rcountMW
    thisElement = docNode.createElement('Devices');
    thisElement.appendChild(docNode.createTextNode('Microwave'));
    docRootNode.appendChild(thisElement);
end

for i=1:rcounttv
    thisElement = docNode.createElement('Devices');
    thisElement.appendChild(docNode.createTextNode('TV'));
    docRootNode.appendChild(thisElement);
end

for i=1:rcountFan
    thisElement = docNode.createElement('Devices');
    thisElement.appendChild(docNode.createTextNode('Fan'));
    docRootNode.appendChild(thisElement);
end

 for i=1:rcountFL
    thisElement = docNode.createElement('Devices');
    thisElement.appendChild(docNode.createTextNode('Flourescent Lamp'));
    docRootNode.appendChild(thisElement);
 end

 for i=1:rcountIL
     thisElement = docNode.createElement('Devices');
     thisElement.appendChild(docNode.createTextNode('Incadescent Lamp'));
     docRootNode.appendChild(thisElement);
 end

 for i=1:rcountAC
     thisElement = docNode.createElement('Devices');
     thisElement.appendChild(docNode.createTextNode('AC'));
     docRootNode.appendChild(thisElement);
 end

 for i=1:rcountDW
     thisElement = docNode.createElement('Devices');
     thisElement.appendChild(docNode.createTextNode('Dish Washer'));
     docRootNode.appendChild(thisElement);
 end

  for i=1:rcountWS
    thisElement = docNode.createElement('Devices');
    thisElement.appendChild(docNode.createTextNode('Washer'));
    docRootNode.appendChild(thisElement);
  end

  for i=1:rcountVC
      thisElement = docNode.createElement('Devices');
      thisElement.appendChild(docNode.createTextNode('Vacumm Cleaner'));
      docRootNode.appendChild(thisElement);
  end 
thisElement = docNode.createElement('Randomizer_count_tv');
thisElement.appendChild(docNode.createTextNode(sprintf('%d',rcounttv)));
docRootNode.appendChild(thisElement);

thisElement = docNode.createElement('Randomizer_count_Fan');
thisElement.appendChild(docNode.createTextNode(sprintf('%d',rcountFan)));
docRootNode.appendChild(thisElement);

thisElement = docNode.createElement('Randomizer_count_FL');
thisElement.appendChild(docNode.createTextNode(sprintf('%d',rcountFL)));
docRootNode.appendChild(thisElement);   

thisElement = docNode.createElement('Randomizer_count_IncadescentLight');
thisElement.appendChild(docNode.createTextNode(sprintf('%d',rcountIL)));
docRootNode.appendChild(thisElement);

thisElement = docNode.createElement('Randomizer_count_dishwasher');
thisElement.appendChild(docNode.createTextNode(sprintf('%d',rcountDW)));
docRootNode.appendChild(thisElement);    

thisElement = docNode.createElement('Randomizer_count_washer');
thisElement.appendChild(docNode.createTextNode(sprintf('%d',rcountWS)));
docRootNode.appendChild(thisElement);          

thisElement = docNode.createElement('Randomizer_count_AC');
thisElement.appendChild(docNode.createTextNode(sprintf('%d',rcountAC)));
docRootNode.appendChild(thisElement);

thisElement = docNode.createElement('Randomizer_count_VC');
thisElement.appendChild(docNode.createTextNode(sprintf('%d',rcountVC)));
docRootNode.appendChild(thisElement);

thisElement = docNode.createElement('Randomizer_count_MW');
thisElement.appendChild(docNode.createTextNode(sprintf('%d',rcountMW)));
docRootNode.appendChild(thisElement);       

thisElement = docNode.createElement('Total_Random_Devices');
thisElement.appendChild(docNode.createTextNode(sprintf('%d',a)));
docRootNode.appendChild(thisElement);

thisElement = docNode.createElement('Total_Randomizer_Amperage');
thisElement.appendChild(docNode.createTextNode(sprintf('%d',int16(rts))));
docRootNode.appendChild(thisElement);
```

I want to close the ESM tag here but it closes before the root. Below is the example.
I want the close the  tag before .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ESM_SIMULATION_TEST>
<TimeStamp>18-Dec-2013 17:19:14</TimeStamp>
<ESM_DEVICES>
  <ESM_ID_1>20136190344.xml</ESM_ID_1>
  <ESM_ID_2>20136190445.xml</ESM_ID_2>
  <Total_Devices>17</Total_Devices>
  <TOTAL_AMPERAGE>69</TOTAL_AMPERAGE>
  <RANDOM_ESM_DEVICES>
     <Devices>TV</Devices>
     <Devices>TV</Devices>
     <Devices>TV</Devices>
     <Devices>Fan</Devices>
     <Devices>Flourescent Lamp</Devices>
     <Devices>Flourescent Lamp</Devices>
     <Devices>Incadescent Lamp</Devices>
     <Devices>Incadescent Lamp</Devices>
     <Devices>Incadescent Lamp</Devices>
     <Devices>AC</Devices>
     <Devices>AC</Devices>
     <Randomizer_count_tv>3</Randomizer_count_tv>
     <Randomizer_count_Fan>1</Randomizer_count_Fan>
     <Randomizer_count_FL>2</Randomizer_count_FL>
     <Randomizer_count_IncadescentLight>3</Randomizer_count_IncadescentLight>
     <Randomizer_count_dishwasher>0</Randomizer_count_dishwasher>
     <Randomizer_count_washer>0</Randomizer_count_washer>
     <Randomizer_count_AC>2</Randomizer_count_AC>
     <Randomizer_count_VC>0</Randomizer_count_VC>
     <Randomizer_count_MW>0</Randomizer_count_MW>
     <Total_Random_Devices>11</Total_Random_Devices>
     <Total_Randomizer_Amperage>44</Total_Randomizer_Amperage>
  </RANDOM_ESM_DEVICES>
```

Comment: "The tag closes _at before the root_ but I want to close it _at the required_. ". Huh? Could you show the XML you are generating, and what you would like to get?

Comment: @Floris: I have edited the question and you can see the XML over there.
Kindly, let me know how do I close the tag before the <RANDOM_ESM_DEVICES>

Comment: Could you include all the code needed to reproduce the XML you are seeing - there are some uninitialized variables right now . Also, show two lots of XML: **as your code creates it**, AND **as you would like it to look** instead of saying "I want to close the ESM tag here but it closes before the root".

Comment: @Floris: I have added an example below and put the whole code. I want to close the <ESM_DEVICES> tag before <RANDOM_ESM_DEVICES>.

Comment: @Floris: No luck :(. I wasn't able to close it. I guess whole syntax has some problem. Can you actually fix it?
Or I get an example problem so that I can fix after getting through it.

Comment: I will take a look tomorrow when I have a computer with Matlab.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in your line

```
docRootNode = docRootNode.appendChild(thisElement);
```

You are redefining the `docRootNode` of the document - after that everything is off. Change it to

```
docRootNode.appendChild(thisElement);
```

and I *think* all will be well. Unfortunately I can't test this right now - not near a computer with Matlab.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very good example in the MATLAB help for writing a XML.
Just try to run in once and play around it with and you should be 
able to understand to how to append and close the tags at the 
desired.
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xmlwrite.html

Comment: Glad you found that reference!